# what is the function of the method times in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to the world of programming and I am working on operator overload, I would like you to explain to me what function the times method fulfills in this exercise.

```
class Vector {
    val arreglo = IntArray(5)

    fun cargar() {
        for (i in arreglo.indices)
            arreglo[i] = (Math.random() * 11 + 1).toInt()
    }

    fun imprimir() {
        for (elemento in arreglo)
            print("$elemento ")
        println()
    }

    operator fun times(valor: Int): Vector {
        var suma = Vector()
        for (i in arreglo.indices)
            suma.arreglo[i] = arreglo[i] * valor
        return suma
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val vec1 = Vector()
    vec1.cargar()
    vec1.imprimir()
    println("El producto de un vector con el número 10 es")
    val vecProductoEnt = vec1 * 10
    vecProductoEnt.imprimir()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function times overloads operator times (*) and lets you write expression vec1 * 10 to multiply every element of Vector by 10.

Answer (score 2):

```
operator fun times(valor: Int): Vector
```

this is the function invoked at this line `val vecProductoEnt = vec1 * 10`.

you can read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html)